# Publishing WPF .Net Core 3 app and Serilog.Sinks.File

Tags: c#, wpf, serilog, .net-core-3.0

NuGet package Serilog.Sinks.File gives an error when publishing.

I am trying to publish a self-contained WPF .NET Core 3.0 app.  The app builds, runs fine publishes fine until Serilog.Sinks.File is added.  Once Serilog.Sinks.File is added to the project, the app builds/runs and even logs correctly.  However, when trying to publish this error is given;

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Exception: Publishing failed.    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.d__23.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__205.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publishing failed.<---
>
> System.Exception: Publishing failed.
>
> ===================

Remove Serilog.Sinks.File and the app publishes.

Even removing the Serilog initialize command and the same error occurs.

Comment: Did you check the exception(s) inside the `AggregateException` to see if it gives any clue?

Comment: @CaioProiete not really, the output in VS, just says Build: 11 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped, then Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped.  No actual error in the output.  A message box appears pointing to a temp file with the above error message.

Comment: Oh that's a shame the log is not flattening the exceptions within the Agg Exception.

Comment: Long shot: Are you configuring the File log via `appSettings.json` or `app.config`? If you are, it's possible the build process is failing to detect the dependency to the File sink... It's worth a quick test... Just put this `Console.WriteLine(typeof(Serilog.FileLoggerConfigurationExtensions));` somewhere in the startup of your app, to create a static dependency to the File Sink assembly, and see if that helps.

Comment: @CaioProiete found the solution, see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution turns out that `Serilog.Sinks.File` is not the correct Nuget package.  You need to use `Serilog.AspNetCore` and then the app is able to publish.